# regex with preg_replace cut a string

Tags: php, regex

I want take of this "-left" from this :
"margin-left-bgc"
I did that, but it's return "margin-left-bgc"

```
$texte = 'margin-left-bgc';
$texte = preg_replace('#^(\-?{1}[a-z]{1,3})$#isU',
'$1', $texte);
echo $texte;
```

What's wrong with my regex ?

Thanks

Comment: str_replace() would be a million times easier and faster

Comment: Your pattern doesn't have any sense. Can you explain better what you are looking for?

Comment: You have an error in your regex `^(\-?{1}  <-- Nested quantifier [a-z]{1,3})$`

Comment: I'm beginner with the regex.
Start by ^ then, 1 dash (\-?), follow by one or three caractere, end with $.

Comment: The very first dash + 4 letters would be `/-[a-z]{1,4}/`

Comment: @sin
$texte = preg_replace('#^(\-?{1})([a-z]{1,3})$#isU', 
    '$1, $2', $texte);
    echo $texte;
I have an error with that:
 Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 7

Comment: Yes, -? means 0 or 1 dash, -?{1} means 0 or 1 dash, 1 time. Its a double quantifier. -? is equivalent to -{0,1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... You just want to do this?

```
<?php
$texte = 'margin-left-bgc';
$texte = preg_replace('/(^\w{6})\-\w{4}\-(\w+$)/','$1-$2', $texte);
echo $texte;
```

Test it out.

Comment: amazing, I'm adapted the number value in the curly brackets, for me its pretty clear, make sens !
`$texte = preg_replace('/(^\w{5,6})\-\w{4,6}\-(\w+$)/','$1-$2', $texte);`
Can you explain me this part with the dash, it is a caracter special ?
I d'like the shortcut
Thanks

Comment: Oh, you can probably get away with not escaping the dash, I do it out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

str_replace() would be a million times easier and faster

```
$texte = 'margin-left-bgc';
echo str_replace('-left','',$texte); //margin-bgc
```

after comment -still doable:

```
echo str_replace(array('-left','-bottom','-right'),'',$texte); //margin-bgc
```

Comment: my text can I being bottom, right, left.
But always with one -, then some text, the another dash

Comment: updated code, still better to use str_replace when it's  a small list of options

Comment: thanks, but in same time I want to learn the regex, but I apreciate that very smart code :)

Comment: it's great to learn it , but does not mean it should always be used, it will always be slower than using str_replace